# Multiple views into ordered Firebase data

Tags: firebase

My application collects photos from a number of sources where each photo (url) is added to a Firebase structure using the timestamp from when the image was posted as the priority:

```
var data = {
   createdAt: new Date(2012, 11, 21).getTime(),
   url: 'http://placekitten.com/320/240',
   likes: 0
}

var images = new Firebase('myapp.firebaseio.com/images')
images.child(createdAt).setWithPriority(data, data.createdAt)
```

The next task is being able to display the list of images in either chronological order or by popularity (*likes*).

Listing and pagination them in chronological is fairly trivial using the [`child_added`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html) event along with [`startAt`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/query/startat.html) and [`limit`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/query/limit.html) but I'm uncertain of how I'm supposed to structure and query my data when viewing them in order of popularity.

I have a few approaches in mind but all of them are pretty crude:

- Fetch every image and do sorting and pagination on the client (there will be a thousand images at most)
- Create another Firebase data structure which is prioritized by popularity (*like count*) with the value of the actual data as a reference pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit both the answers I would have picked. With a thousand at most, I think you're going to save time and energy to just do it on the client.

Another brute force approach that comes to mind, if you need them to be done on the server and also don't want to duplicate data, is to create an index. This isn't efficient as a SQL index, but it's still viable and I'll throw it out here to generate ideas.

Essentially, you would have your photos table:

```
/photos/$photo_id/  (prioritized by create data)
```

And then an index:

```
/photos_indexed_by_likes/$photo_id  (prioritized by likes
```

In this way, you can do something like this:

```
FB.child('photos_indexed_by_likes').endAt().limit(10).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    // the snapshot contains the id of a photo, so we fetch it here
    FB.child('photos/'+snapshot.val()).once('value', function(ss) {
        addPresortedPhotoToList( ss.val() );
    });
});
```

By only achieving the records you're going to show on this page, this is viable. It does request each photo individually, but may not a big deal unless you're serving up to a twitter sized audience :)

It's always a trade-off. In this case you trade storage space for speed for bandwidth :)

*UPDATE*

By the way, I don't think you need to add a sort priority for create data. The values are naturally sorted by creation time.

Comment: The payload is ~600kb at a thousand images so that's something I can live with for now.

It doesn't seem like Firebase compresses any outgoing data though which I find a bit strange since the compressed data is only ~100kb)

Comment: Maybe you should store the images in a file system and just access the URLs via firebase, which will drop the payload to nothing?

Comment: Both of these approaches are good solutions. I'd recommend the index approach, though rather than once() I'd use on() to ensure those items update if they're ever changed. 

As far as compression -- this will be coming. We just haven't gotten to that yet. Storing images in Firebase should work fine (the storing just the URLs is fine too).

Comment: The images are already storeded on S3 by the time I collect them so that's not a problem. Is there a way to make Firebase stream or chunk the transfer so I don't have to wait for all thousand images before displaying the first 100?

I understand I can use the limit() function but AFAIK setting that to 100 would cause the next 100 to be removed from the reference once loaded.

Comment: I don't think you need to wait at all. `child_added` will give you each one as it arrives. It is essentially streamed. If you are sorting client side, then you'd simply run your comparator on each to decide where it is spliced into the list

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful responses, I feel this answer touches both practically available solutions so I'm accepting it.